How to determine if previous call to task is completed
I have a .NET 8 wpf application that used the Microsoft Community Toolkit for MVVM and Microsoft Extension Dependency injection as well as EF-Core framework.  In addition to Views and Viewmodels I have a Repo class that uses async messages to query data using EF-Core.
The app creates a list view and the user clicks on an item that triggers the items property change and calls an async method in the repository that retrieves a record from the database.
The problem occurs if the user selects a new item, before the previous item was retrieved (i.e. they clicked on the wrong item and want to click on another one).  I get the error "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. "
I have tried changing the datacontext and the service scopes, but it doesn't solve the problem. Lets save that question for a different thread.
In this scenario, a new call is made to the async method whenever the user changes the selected item.  How can I determine if the previous call has been completed before executing a new call?
The solution I implemented in setting a property within the method that determines if the task is completed kind of works, but is there a better way to determine if the task is finished? Can I make the new request wait until the previous task is completed, or cancel the previous task and start a new one.  (Either scenario is sufficient for the apps needs as once the user clicks on a new item the previous one is irrelevant).
Attached are what I believe are relevant code snippets of the App.cs, The ViewModel, and the Repo.
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider();          
    }

    public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {                
        base.OnStartup(e);          
    }

    private IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContext<bardv2hContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer("defaultconnstring"); },ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        
        services.AddTransient<ILocalRepo, LocalRepo>();
        services.AddTransient<ViewModel>();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}

public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ILocalRepo _localRepo;
    private bool _taskcompleted = true;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private short ubCounter;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private short selectedCounter;

    async partial void OnSelectedCounterChanged(short value)
    {

        await getSelectedResearch(value);
    }

    async partial void OnUbCounterChanged(short value)
    {
        await getSelectedResearch(value);
    }

    async internal Task getSelectedResearch(short value)
    {
        if (!_taskcompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);
        }
        _taskcompleted = false;
        SelectedResearch = await _localRepo.OneResearchbyCounter(value);
        _taskcompleted = true;
    }

    public ResearchViewModelC1()
    {
        _localRepo = App.Current.serviceProvider.GetService<ILocalRepo>();
    }
}

public class LocalRepo : ILocalRepo
{
    private readonly bardv2hContext _localdb;
    
    public LocalRepo(bardv2hContext localdb)
    {
        _localdb = localdb;
    }

    public async Task<Research> OneResearchbyCounter(short counter)
    {
        var res = await _localdb.Researches
            .Where(r=>r.Counter == counter)
            .Include(r=>r.Inres)
            .Include(r=>r.ApprovedResearch)
            .Include(r=>r.Actualpayments)
            .Include(r=>r.FiscalReports)
            .Include(r=>r.Scireports)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        return res;
    }
}

I tried using the DBContextFactory based on this sample, but I cannot get it to work.  I changed my app.cs to this:
public partial class App : Application
{
    public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider();          
    }

    public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {                
        base.OnStartup(e);          
    }

    private IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddDbContextFactory<bardv2hContext><bardv2hContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer("defaultconnstring"); });
        
        services.AddTransient<ILocalRepo, LocalRepoWF>();
        services.AddTransient<ViewModel>();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}

And the Repo to this:
public LocalRepoWF(Func<dbContext> localdb)
 {
     _factory = localdb;
     dbContext _localdb;
 } public LocalRepoWF(Func<dbContext> localdb)
 {
     _factory = localdb;
 }
  public async Task<Mymodel> selModel(string InvCode)
  {
      using (var _localdb = _factory.Invoke())
      { return await _localdb.Model.Find(InvCode); }
  }

But I get the error

Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Func`1[dbContext]' while
attempting to activate 'LocalRepoWF'

I tried registering the service like this:
    .AddScoped<ILocalRepo, LocalRepoWF>(lr => new LocalRepoWF(() => lr.GetService<dbContext>()))

But I get an error message when calling the procedure in the Repo: "Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application."

Why did you ConfigureAwait(false)? I don't think you want that.

I tried without the ConfiguareAwait(false), but it didn't solve the problem.  As you can probably see from my question, I'm not the biggest async/await guru, but all the 'experts' suggest adding this on, so I left it.

The easy solutions is to either block any new request until the current is complete, for example by showing a modal dialog, or diabling UI elements. Or use short lived db context objects, so each requests creates, uses and disposes the db context. Allowing for multiple concurrent requests.

" but all the 'experts' suggest adding this on" - this is the one specific case, where you shouldn't. You want to return to the calling context, don't you?

This should all work, even as scoped instead of transient. I think I would try to get the repo out of the model so it is just a POCO. Besides that code looks like I would expect and DI should fire up different contexts per client request.

All very good points.  I think disabling UI would be the most practical.  Thomas, could you explain your comment a liitle better?  Should I inject the dbcontext into the viewmodel and then call the repo?  Are you suggesting that I call the dbcontext from the VM?

@Fildor The VM call is returning to the calling context. And that is the only thing that matters in this case.

@HaimKatz You should inject an IDbContextFactory<TContext> to build a DbContext on each request

@Sir Rufo Right. Missed that it's two layers.

Sir Rufi, I tried using the DBContextFactory approach but was unsuccessful. (See additions to my question above).  I did solve at least this problem by not injecting the DBContext into the Repo, but creating a new Context on the Repo's construction:  public Repo() {_db = new dbContext)}.  This also improved the responsiveness of the application.

Thank you Sir Rufo the use of the IDBContextFactory solved my problem.  Not only did it remove the error, but the program is far more responsive.  I will post my corrected code here for future reference.  Its based on this sample The service injection was changed to this:
    public partial class App : Application
{
  public IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }

public App()
{
    serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider();          
}

public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{                
    base.OnStartup(e);          
}

private IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddDbContextFactory<bardv2hContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer("defaultconnstring"); },ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
    
    services.AddTransient<ILocalRepo, LocalRepo>();
    services.AddTransient<ViewModel>();
    return services.BuildServiceProvider();
}

And my repo was changed to this. (Note the code in the original question was based on an older efcore version) (The ViewModel remained the same)
  private readonly IDbContextFactory<bardv2hContext> _factory;

  public LocalRepoWF(IDbContextFactory<bardv2hContext> localdb)
  {
      _factory = localdb;
  }
 
  public async Task<Models.Localdbc.Investigator> selInvestigatorbyInvCode(string InvCode)
  {
      using (var _localdb = _factory.CreateDbContext())
      { return await _localdb.Investigators.Where(i => i.InvCode == InvCode).Include(i => i.InvTypes).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); }
  } 

